# merge varying number of columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, merge

i am trying to merge data frames with various columns. subsetting them i think requires different treatment depending if its with 1 or >1 columns so i tried with if statements, but its not working and im not sure why. any tips would be great thanks so much

edit - the index contains duplicate values so cant use pd.concat - i want to keep these

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'cat':[0,2,1], 'dog':[1,2,3]}).set_index([pd.Index([2, 2, 4])])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'mouse':[1,2,3],'parrot':[0,1,2],'elephant':[0,1,2]}).set_index([pd.Index([1, 2, 4])])

# b can be varying but for this instance lets use two columns
# b = 'parrot'
b = 'parrot', 'mouse'

if len(b) > 0:
    if len(b) > 1:
        out = df1.merge(df2[[*b]],left_index=True, right_index=True)
    else:
        out = df1.merge(df2[b],left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dataframe does not contains multiindex columns, you can use **[`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)** to select the required columns in `df2` then use **[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)** to concatenate dataframe `df1` with the selected columns along `axis=1`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2.loc[:, b]], axis=1)
```

Sample run:

```
# b = 'mouse'
   cat  dog  mouse
0    0    1      1
1    1    2      2
2    2    3      3


# b = 'mouse', 'parrot'
   cat  dog  mouse  parrot
0    0    1      1       0
1    1    2      2       1
2    2    3      3       2
```

Comment: this is a great answer thank you! however....the index does include duplicates in some cases. good spot, i will add that to my blurb

Comment: @siash In that case you could use `join`, check `df1.join(df2.loc[:, b])`

Answer (score 0):

```
b = 'parrot'
len(b) = 6

b = 'parrot', 'mouse'
len(b) = 2

You can fix this by using lists
b = ['parrot']
and 
b = ['parrot', 'mouse']

df2[[*b]] should become df2[b]
```